# How to place the go to desktop button like windows

Tags: windows, migration

Sometimes I have to use windows, and I think that the go to desktop button position is pretty convenient since you just go fully into right and bottom and you will be positioned, while in the linux button, you have to actually position it in the right way.

It there anyway that I can place the button into bottom-right?

Thanks

Comment: What is the desktop environment you use? Which button are you referring to? What is that button supposed to do?

Comment: well, the "go to desktop" button should change your screen to the desktop haha